# Phrases/idioms to say you should have done a certain thing without using "regret"

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, idioms, synonyms, idiom-requests

Are there any suitable phrases/idioms to describe that I should have done a certain thing and I regret not having done it?
For example, I have one regret from my school days, which is that I didn't visit the historical museum near our school building. As I found out recently that the museum has been closed down several months ago, I completely missed the opportunity to go there during my life.

Comment: Why don't you want to use _regret_? You could simply say "I wish I had visited that museum while I had the chance".

Comment: There are many [synonyms for regret](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/regret) with different connotations, depending on how bad your actions were, how much you regret, how sorry you are, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Act in haste repent at leisure

No use crying over spilled milk

A stitch in time saves nine

The road not taken

If only I didn't know now what I didn't know then

Look before you leap

Oh what might have been

Youth is wasted on the young

Where have all the years gone

Comment: Or "If only I knew now what I didn't know then?" Different from some song lyrics?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use one or both of these two phrases, "If I only knew then what I know now" and/or "Alas, that ship has sailed".  The first idiom could be part of a sentence that includes details specific to the situation you wish to describe or it could stand on its own afterward.  Both fit the bill as far as expressing a desire to have done something differently as well as regret resulting from the knowledge that those decisions/actions are final in that there will never be an opportunity to amend or reverse them.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> hindsight is 20/20

> a case of I-told-you-so

Answer (score 1):

Check it in other Germanic languages and try to find a hint.

Take the German:

> "Hinterher ist man immer schlauer."

Gives:

> "Afterwards one is always wiser." (from [Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/german-english/translation/hinterher+ist+man+immer+schlauer.html), [dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc/?s=Hinterher+ist+man+immer+schlauer))

> "Hindsight is easier than foresight."

(the other "Hindsight is always 20/20" was already said in the other answer)

You could look at it from the other side. Ponder whether it is so bad at all, at least, you found out about it now and regret not to have been there. Would be worse if you did not care anyway.

You could change the broader wording of the Goethe proverb

> "Knowing is not enough; we must apply. Willing is not enough; we must do."

Taken from [Jane E Ferrie, ‘Knowing is not enough; we must apply. Willing is not enough; we must do.’, International Journal of Epidemiology, Volume 43, Issue 6, December 2014, Pages 1671–1677, https://doi.org/10.1093/ije/dyu230](https://academic.oup.com/ije/article/43/6/1671/711714?login=false)

And make it: "Willing is not enough; we must know. (Goethe must have missed something)."

as a whole phrase, with the brackets. Since that Goethe idiom is famous, this change of the idiom might be understood by at least a good share, and the rest will guess it.

Or, to make it clearer to a reader who does not know the Goethe proverb by heart:

"Knowing is not enough; we must apply. Willing is not enough; we must do. But one thing Goethe must have been missing: willing is not enough; we must know."